# how to match specific information on a file for login?

Tags: php, forms, validation, file-io

got a question, that I can't find a solution for.  Before I continue with my question, just a brief overview of what the code is suppose to do (This is for a class project in a beginning php course).  User automatically starts on the index.php page.  Once the quantities are inputed, it will take them to the login.php page.  If they have a login, then it will take them to the invoice.php page.  If not, then it will take them to the register.php page, then go to the invoice.php page.

Here's where I run into a problem, how do I match the username and password (inputed from the user registration page) from my user.dat file to the login page?  It's frustrating because we really didn't go over it in class :(

Any help will be greatly appreciated, feel free to give feed back on any of the code presented :)

Thank you so much in advance folks!  This site has definitely ease some of the coding headaches :P

**login.php**

```
<h3>
    <center>
        Please Login
    </center>
</h3>
<?php
include "functions.inc";

//if the form data is clicked... if all valid.. display invoice... otherwise display error
$datafile = "users.dat";

$file = file_get_contents($datafile);
if(!strpos($file, "search string")) {
echo "String not found!";
}

   if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
   {
     if(!strpos($file, "search string")) {
echo "String not found!";
}
      header('Location: registration.php');

   }

   else 
       if (array_key_exists('register', $_POST))
   {

      header('Location: invoice.php');
   }


?>








<?php//made the user login menu into a nice table that will center the username and password in the middle of the page.?>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="invoice.php">
        <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>:</td>';    
        <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
</table>
        <center><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'></center>
        </form>

        <?php
/*This code will allow a new user to go to the registration page and register for the site
 * before buying anything.
 */
        ?>
    <br>   
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="registration.php">
        <center><input type='submit' name='Register' value='New User? Click here.'></center>
        </form>
```

**registration.php**

```
<html>
    <h4>
        <center>
            New User Registration
        </center>
    </h4>
    <body>

        <?php
        /*
         * What this code does, is it takes the users registration information, and stores it in a file.
         * After that what I hope to do is to retrive the same file when the user is on the login page and if 
         * the login matches whats in the file, then proceed to the invoice page.
         */
include "functions.inc";

    // Define the datafile to hold the $users array
    $datafile = "users.dat";

    // See if the user has submitted something
    if (array_key_exists('register', $_POST))
    {
        // Get the new user info
            $the_user = $_POST['newUser'];


// Load the file of users and store it in $users
        $users = arrayfile_to_array($datafile);


        // Validate user name and password
        if (user_exists($the_user['ID'], $users))
        {
            echo "<p><center>Please fill in all text boxes</center></p>";
        }
        else
        {
            // If valid, save to the file of users
            $users[] = $the_user;
            array_to_arrayfile($users, $datafile);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!file_exists($datafile))  // Data file doesn't exist, so create it
        {
            $users = array();
            array_to_arrayfile($users, $datafile);
        }
    }
?>

        <?php
       // my defined error values 
      $errEmail    = "";
      $errUser     = "";
      $errPass     = "";


      if(isset($_POST["register"])){

        // User must be digits and letters
        if(preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,}$/", $_POST['newUser']['ID']) === 0)
          $errUser = '<span class="error">Username must be more than 5 characters and contain letters and numbers.</span>';

        // Password must be strong
        if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST['newUser']['password']) === 0)
          $errPass = '<span class="error">Password must be at least 8 characters and must contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit</span>';

        //Email validation
        if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]\w+(\.\w+)*\@\w+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/", $_POST['newUser']['email']) === 0)
          $errEmail = '<span class="error">example: chars(.chars)@chars(.chars).chars(2-4)</span>';
      }  
  ?>

        <form action = "<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method= 'POST'> 
            <center>
                <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td ><input name="newUser[ID]" type="text" size="16" value="">
          <?php  if(isset($errUser) and $errUser !='') echo $errUser; ?>
                        </td >
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="newUser[password]" type="password" size="16" value="">
          <?php  if(isset($errPass) and $errPass !='') echo $errPass; ?>
                        </td >
                    </tr>
                                         <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="newUser[email]" type="text" size="50" value="">
          <?php  if(isset($errEmail) and $errEmail !='') echo $errEmail; ?>
                        </td >
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                    </tr>          
                </table>
                <input type='submit' name='register' value='Register'>
            </center>    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Romel we don't know what's relevant.  it takes time to read and understand all that... if you just show us where you have the data, what the data looks like, and the code where you need to make the comparison... it takes probably 30 seconds to figure out.

Comment: I don't think putting user information in .dat file is safe...

Comment: @UdayHiwarale - it's a class project apparently... safety doesn't matter...!